# Number of Nodes in a Cycle of a graph

Tags: c++, graph, digraphs

I am trying to find the number of nodes in a cycle of a graph. I am using recursion and DFS to calculate the number of nodes in all the cycles of the graph.Here is the calculating function in C++.

```
int iscyclic(int node,bool visited[],bool rec[],vector<int>g[])
{
    if(!visited[node])
{
    visited[node] = true;
    rec[node] = true;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    for(it=g[node].begin();it!=g[node].end();it++)
    {
        if(!visited[*it] && iscyclic(*it,visited,rec,g))
        {
            kount++;
        }
        else if(rec[*it])
            kount++;
    }
}
rec[node] = false;
return kount;
}
```

The `Visited` and `rec` array are set to false by default and `kount` has been globally set as `0`. The `kount` is supposed to calculate the number of nodes in a cycle of the directed graph.However there are cases where the answer is wrong. Please help.I Have recently started learning graph theory.

Comment: "However there are cases where the answer is wrong." - example?

Comment: number of nodes = 4

number of edges = 4

And the Connection is as follows:-
1 -2,
2 -3,
3 -4,
4 -3,

Comment: The number of cycles is exponential in the size of the graph, are you sure you are calculating them all?

Comment: Yes,the number of cycles are taken into account but what bugs me is the number of nodes in a cycle

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this:

```
else if(rec[*it])
   kount++;
```

Also, you need to make sure that the starting node (the one you call the function with) is really part of a cycle.

Third thing - you return `kcount` as result of your function, when you atually should return `true` or `false` based on the fact whether you encountered a cycle in this branch or not.

Comment: Okay ,  but on returning boolean values i would get the result that weather there exists a cycle or not but i am interested in finding the number of nodes present in that cycle

Comment: Nope. You either way obtain the result in `kcount`. It is global and you can always access it. Whether you found a cycle or not, on the other hand, is important result telling you whether the currently processed branch of the recursion triggered successful result or not. In case of success you should discontinue considering the other branches